# How can I turn the first column in a dataset into row names?

Tags: import, dataset

I've used [`SemanticImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) to import to a `"TSV"` spreadsheet into a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html). Each row starts with a year name and then has 12 values, one for each month. [`SemanticImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) correctly interpreted the column names as months, and the first column as year, but the row entries under year are interpreted as data rather than names. Is there a way to turn them into names for the rows?

Comment: Can you post (a subset of) your CSV data in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: I've never used Pastebin and am not sure how to show you the data but I did post a subset at: https://pastebin.com/vihHYQsf

Comment: Actually you [file](https://pastebin.com/vihHYQsf) is more like `"TSV"` rather than `"CSV"`. So I correct the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy) on the "Year" column, and then drop the "Year" column:

```
import = SemanticImport["https://pastebin.com/raw/vihHYQsf"];

ds = GroupBy[import, "Year", First][All, KeyDrop["Year"]]
```

[image]

Then, we can extract the Jul, 2010 value using:

```
ds[Key[2010], "Jul"]
```

> 560.7

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe `SemanticImport[]` has the flexibility you want, so I'll use plain `Import[]` instead (which is much faster) and then do some post-processing:

```
raw = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/vihHYQsf", "Table"];
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[IntegerString /@ raw[[2 ;;, 1]],
                               AssociationThread[raw[[1, 2 ;;]], #] & /@
                               raw[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]]
```

[image: dataset]

where I needed to use `IntegerString[]` to converts integers to proper labels.

For example,

```
ds["2009", "Oct"]
   585.
```